# How to fix table width breaking out from div?

Tags: html, css

Table works normally in 100%, but when I zoom in the table width is not following the screen size. I want to use overflow-scroll to make this work but the scroll bar is not showing.

I don't want to use table-layout fixed with width 100%.

Image below shows the table out of div that makes my upper div (title) going out of div too
[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
            <div class="breadCrumbs">

                <h2 id="breadhead">Report Management</h2>
                 
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="frameBody p-4 p-md-5 pt-5">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 tableCover" style="overflow:scroll" > 
                <table id="tblBranchs" class="table table-bordered " > 
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                            <td >Kode Branch</td>
                                            <td width="5%">Grup</td>
                                            <td >Nama</td>
                                            <td width="20%">Alamat</td>
                                            <td >Bank</td>
                                            <td >Nama Bank</td>
                                            <td >No. Rekening</td>
                                            <td >Kota</td>
                                            <td >Tindakan</td> 
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>12345</td>
                                        <td>12345</td>
                                        <td>12345</td>
                                        <td>123453iuuihefsbefjhsbfjsbfjbsf</td>
                                        <td>12345</td>
                                        <td>12345kl3jhsekfnkljsebf</td>
                                        <td>12345</td>
                                        <td>12345</td>
                                        <td>12345</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
    
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    margin-left: 200px;
}

#breadCrumbs{
    padding-top: 4rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    padding-left: 3rem;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 13px 13px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px #d4d4d6;
}

.table{
    width:100%;
}
```

How to correct this table problem. If i'm using table layout fixed. It shows all table column without scroll but it looks bad

[image]

**EDIT
Seems like it's because tableCover width is set 100%. If i set width to (e.g 700px) this is works. But how can make tableCover width following width of the content class width (white screen width) ?

**EDIT 2
The scroll is shown, but why is the table out of div?
This works well if i hide the sidebar, but why it's not responsive when sidebar is active?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```css
#content
{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
#breadCrumbs
{
    padding-top: 4rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    padding-left: 3rem;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 13px 13px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px #d4d4d6;
}
.table
{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Hello, i need my margin left to position my content div against side navigation div

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS code like this:

```
*,
*:before,    
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#content{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    margin-left: 200px;
}

#breadCrumbs{
    padding-top: 4rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    padding-left: 3rem;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 13px 13px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px #d4d4d6;
}
.table {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hello, it's not working. Box sizing is already added before, and display block doesn't change anything